# Como pegar as teclas direcionais em C/C++?

Tags: c, c++

É possível pegar as teclas direcionais (famosas setinhas) do teclado? se sim, como?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Em C/C++ puro não dá para fazer isso.
Para lidar com as teclas direcionais você deve trabalhar com uma API específica.

Você pode fazer isso usando a [API do Windows (Win32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff818516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [SDL2](http://www.libsdl.org/), [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/), [Allegro](http://alleg.sourceforge.net/), [Ogre3d](http://www.ogre3d.org/), [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/), [Qt](http://qt-project.org/), [wxWidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org) e etc, que fazem a interação entre o sistema operacional e o seu código.

---

Por exemplo, com `SDL`, no loop de execução você teria algo do tipo:

```
SDL_Event event;

while( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) )
{
    switch( event.type )
    {
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            printf( "Seta para baixo pressionada\n" );
            break;
        case SDL_KEYUP:
            printf( "Seta para cima pressionada\n" );
            break;
        default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Já no `wxWidgets` seria algo assim:

```
void MyWin::OnKeyPress(wxKeyEvent& event)
{
    long keycode = event.GetKeyCode();
    if (keycode == WXK_UP)
    {
        // Seta para cima pressionada.
        event.Skip();
    }
}
```

Já no `SFML` é algo do tipo:

```
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left))
{
    // pressionou para esquerda
}
```

---

O ideal é você escolher uma API própria para o projeto que você quer executar, pois a forma como cada uma delas trata isso é um pouco diferente. Por exemplo, para jogos pode ser SDL, SFML, Ogre3D. Para programas, pode ser Qt, wxWidgets, WIN32, GTK e etc.

A principal diferença é que nas API's de jogos as teclas são verificadas em "tempo real". Já nas APIS para desenvolvimento de programas desktop, as teclas são tratas como eventos.

Comment: tem algum exemplo?

Comment: Vou editar minha resposta e adicionar.

Comment: Lembro do tempo que se fazia isso capturando interrupções, sem API nem nada... mas estamos falando de MS-DOS :)

Comment: Acho que dava para pegar as setas direcionais com o `conio.h`.

Comment: como não tem como fazer em C puro se as ferramentas listadas acima são feitas em C puro ?

Comment: Por favor edite sua resposta. Existe sim maneiras de fazer em linguem C. Inclusive algumas ferramentas que voce citou sao totalmente baseadas em linguagem C.

Answer (score 4):

Uma forma de fazer isso no Windows é usar [`Hooks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), que é uma técnica usada para interceptar, monitorar e modificar o comportamento de [chamadas de sistema](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chamada_de_sistema), funções, mensagens e eventos.

Você pode detectar as teclas direcionais da seguinte forma:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

HHOOK hook;
KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT kbdStruct;

LRESULT __stdcall HookCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
   if ((nCode >= 0) && wParam == WM_KEYDOWN){
        kbdStruct = *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam);
        if (kbdStruct.vkCode == VK_LEFT)  
          puts("A seta da esquerda foi pressionada");
        if (kbdStruct.vkCode == VK_RIGHT) 
          puts("A seta da direita foi pressionada");
        if (kbdStruct.vkCode == VK_DOWN)  
          puts("A seta para baixo foi pressionada");
        if (kbdStruct.vkCode == VK_UP)    
          puts("A seta para cima foi pressionada");
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

void SetHook(){
   if (!(hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, HookCallback, NULL, 0))){
     // Erro ao iniciar o processo de escuta
   }
}

int main(){
    MSG msg;
    SetHook(); // Instala a escuta
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) { }

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook); // Desinstala a escuta
    return 0;
}
```

Ao pressionar as teclas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[**Documentação**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Mas para a utilização dos Hooks você teve que utilizar API do Windows. Seria puro mesmo se existisse algo do tipo: `std::cin.get() == KEY_LEFT`.

Comment: -1: `SetWindowsHookEx` não é C nem C++.

Comment: @pepper_chico Negativar uma resposta correta e que pode ajudar quem precisa disso por *pedantry*? ok, está no seu direito, mas..

Comment: corrigido, removido. @GuilhermeBernal não sou a favor de espalhar informações errôneas, mesmo que sejam úteis por meios tortuosos.

Answer (score 2):

Eu fiz em C para pegar setas direcionais, dá uma olhada nesse link do github:
https://github.com/CarlosAdir/C-Programs/tree/master/Tutoriais

Baixe toda a pasta e execute o arquivo 8-extras.c e veja como funciona.
O arquivo kbhitgetch.pdf explica e tem uma boa base para entender como funciona por trás.